# create a directory like windows explorer and store information a text file

Tags: java, thread-synchronization

guys i have got a  problem in which i have to create a directory which keeps a text file which keeps the information about all the files. Like file `created, last modified , type etc..` its not a big deal till i have to maintain this record of the static files(already present in the directory). But what happens when some new files are added, how do i check that the last modified thing. For the static files, initially i have set the class variable as zero and later the variable is compared with the last modified value. My question is what happens when a new file is added ? A new object is created every time a new file is added ?
I tried that way but its turning out to be highly tedious? Am i moving in the right direction? It has to be done in `java`. In a real fix. Kindly help guys. I hope am clear with my doubt.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: How is what you are doing different than what the OS does to keep info on files in a folder? Why not use the OS to look up files and dates and such?

Comment: its an assignment sir -_-

Comment: and am not able to do it. I want to find a way out. CURIOSITY !

Comment: am using watcher service API\